# Dynamic Linq and Where Clause & NOT Contains

Tags: linq, dynamic

`.Where("MyColumn.Contains(@0)", "column_value")`

I would like to know the syntax or the correct way to have NOT contains in dynamic linq.

Comment: Not really sure but try `Where(!"MyColumn.Contains(@0)", "column_value")` or `Where("!MyColumn.Contains(@0)", "column_value")`

Comment: I don't see how the first could work, you can't "not" a string, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @RonanThibaudau `Contains` doesn't return a string, it returns a Boolean, so `!` should work just fine.

Comment: @NathanA I didn't say contains returns a string, in the first example he put the not OUTSIDE of the string, so he's effectively noting the string (he wrote !"MyColumn" instead of "!MyColumn"). Since this is the only difference with the 2nd example it's a clear logical error, he's NOT-ing the string.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Got it. Sorry, I missed that very tiny detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of these worked for me:

```
collection.Where("!MyColumn.Contains(@0)", "value");
collection.Where("MyColumn.Contains(@0) = false", "value");
collection.Where("MyColumn.Contains(@0) == false", "value");
```

I used System.Linq.Dynamic (version 1.0.2) from NuGet.

Comment: null propagating `np(MyColumn.Contains(@0) == false, false)` will not work, np() needs the first parameter to be a property, however `np(!MyColumn.Contains(@0), false)` works just fine